# Invalid Date DataGrid Mui React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui, datagrid, timestamp

I'm having problem converting my timestamp firestore to simple date ("dd, mm, yy") this is my code:

```
{
      field: "createdAt",
      type: "date",
      headerName: "Tarih",
      width: 240,
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        if (params.value === null) {
          return "";
        } else {
          const fireBaseTime = new Date(
            params.seconds * 1000 + params.nanoseconds / 1000000
          );
          const date = fireBaseTime.toDateString();
          return date;
        }
      },
    },
```

Comment: What is the problem specifically? Are you getting an error or is your function returning an incorrect value (or none at all)?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting at the end of the table "Invalid Date" https://snipboard.io/7sO49w.jpg